# Piechart created using d3pie.js in angularjs 1.5, has issue with segment pullout event

Tags: angularjs, d3pie.js

I have created a pie chart using d3pie.js in angularjs 1.5
when clicked on a segment of the pie it doesn't close the previously 
clicked segment of the pie.
Below is the code contains the html and libraries used with controller 
part where the pie chart is generated.
the  has the scripts or library to be used for the chart. it also contains a div which is  the placeholder for pie chart.

libraries:

```
     <script src="angular.js"></script>
     <script src="d3.min.js"></script>
     <script src="d3pie.min.js"></script>
```

html code:

```
 <div id="pie"></div>
```

in the controller part pie is actually created.

```
getDevivesApp.controller('getPieChartController', function($scope){
        var pie = new d3pie("pie", {
        header: {
            title: {
                text: "A very simple example pie"
            }
        },
        data: {
            content: [
                { label: "JavaScript", value: 50 },
                { label: "Ruby", value: 20 },
                { label: "Java", value: 30},
            ]
         },
       callbacks: {
        onMouseoverSegment: function(info) {
            console.log("mouse in", info);
        },
        onMouseoutSegment: function(info) {
            console.log("mouseout:", info);
        }
     }
    });
});
```

once the piechart is created, when clicked on one of the segment , 
 previously clicked segment of the pie chart will not be closed.
 Libraries used angularJS version 1.5
 d3pie.min.js version  0.2.1
 d3.min.js version 4.12.2.

Comment: Any help on this will really be appreciated.